# How may I replace a string in an XML file?

Tags: awk, sed, perl, xml

I am trying to replace the string inside an XML file.

From

```xml
<hello="value" exampleno="xxxx:yyyyyyyy/dd=eeeee-ffffff,aa=bb ccc,dd=eeee,ff=gggg,hh=iii,jj=kkk,ll=mmmm" />
```

I want to replace only the

```
aa=bb ccc,dd=eeee
```

part with

```
xx=yy yyy,zz=aaaa,bb=cc ddd
```

How to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Your example is not a valid XML file. A tag's name can not contain `=`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the XML is well formed, like something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <hello exmapleno="Other attribute's value"/>
  <hello exampleno="xxxx:yyyyyyyy/dd=eeeee-ffffff,aa=bb ccc,dd=eeee,ff=gggg,hh=iii,jj=kkk,ll=mmmm"/>
</root>
```

... then you may replace the `aa=bb ccc,dd=eeee` part of the `exampleno` attribute's value in the `hello` node using `xmlstarlet`, like so:

```bash
xmlstarlet edit \
    --var searchstring '"aa=bb ccc,dd=eeee"' \
    --var replacement  '"xx=yy yyy,zz=aaaa,bb=cc ddd"'  \
    --update '//hello/@exampleno[contains(.,$searchstring)]' \
    --expr 'concat(
        substring-before(.,$searchstring),
        $replacement,
        substring-after(.,$searchstring)
    )' file.xml
```

(Note that the `--var` variables are Xpath expressions and that the strings therefore must contain literal double quotes.)

Or, without the fancy variable in the XPath expression:

```bash
xmlstarlet edit \
    --update '//hello/@exampleno[contains(.,"aa=bb ccc,dd=eeee")]' \
    --expr 'concat(
        substring-before(.,"aa=bb ccc,dd=eeee"),
        "xx=yy yyy,zz=aaaa,bb=cc ddd",
        substring-after(.,"aa=bb ccc,dd=eeee")
    )' file.xml
```

This would modify *all* `hello` nodes in the document containing an `exampleno` attribute with the search string.  Would you want to hand-pick one of these nodes, then use a more specific path to it than `//hello`.

What the command does is to locate all nodes that match the XPath expression `//node/@exampleno` (i.e., the `exampleno` attribute of all `hello` nodes), with the added condition that the value must contain the search string.  It then updates the value of the matching attributes according to the `--expr` expression.  This expression picks out the part before and after the (first occurrence of the) target string in the attribute's value and concatenates these with the new string in the middle.

The output is written to the terminal, but you will get in-place editing with the aptly named `--inplace` option.

Test running, with shortened option names:

```bash
$ xmlstarlet ed --var s '"aa=bb ccc,dd=eeee"' --var r '"xx=yy yyy,zz=aaaa,bb=cc ddd"' -u '//hello/@exampleno[contains(.,$s)]' -x 'concat(substring-before(.,$s),$r,substring-after(.,$s))' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <hello exmapleno="Other attribute's value"/>
  <hello exampleno="xxxx:yyyyyyyy/dd=eeeee-ffffff,xx=yy yyy,zz=aaaa,bb=cc ddd,ff=gggg,hh=iii,jj=kkk,ll=mmmm"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Good job ! Nice use of xmlstarlet

Comment: @GillesQuenot I just wish I could have used `replace()`...

Comment: Dear Kusal, Thanks a lot for the response. Is it possible to provide Unix solutions? As the XML files on Unix server and xmlstarlet not exists. Thanks

Comment: That is a Unix solution. Xmlstarlet is rather easy to install, even just as unprivileged user.

Comment: @Ganesh this is a UNIX solution. You can ask your system administrators to install the application. It's available for most platforms, and has considerable support from IBM (amongst others)

Comment: Yeah on a machine where many XML files occur, I'd expect that to be there.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but Unix admin refuse to install xmlstarlet on our AIX servers as this is needed in multiple servers not just one server. If anything with sed tool then it can help? Thanks

Comment: @Ganesh In a situation like this, I would personally speak to my manager to get them to talk to the admin and their team. A system administrator's role at a company is to provide a usable computer system that the employees may use to benefit the company and your stakeholders.  Yes, we could give you a `sed` one-liner, but please, let your manager and the sysadmin know that no `sed` one-liner is going to be parsing XML reliably and that you should not be held responsible for any loss of revenue or other damages incurred by running sub-par code. Also, I will not write that one-liner for you.

Comment: @Kusalananda I tried the one liner of sed and never works and I would like Unix based solution rather xmlstarlet . Thanks so far, Sorry being a pain :-) Thanks

Comment: @Ganesh As a few of us have said already, this is a Unix site, and we will give you Unix answers. The `xmlstarlet` tool is a commonly used XML parser and processor for working efficiently and reliably with XML data on any Unix system. It is available for AIX and other commercial Unix variants. You have the option to wait for another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you don't want to install `xmlstarlet` because you asked [the same question again here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/722646/how-to-replace-the-string-using-unix-shell-commands) mentioning that you just want unix commands.

First of all:
**Don't ask the same question twice !**
Just use a comment to mention that you want to do it in another way.

I am assuming you mention "unix commands" because you don't want to install extra software.

Nowadays most unix-based operating systems already contain Perl in a basic installation, so you can do it like this:

```bash
perl -pne 's/aa=bb ccc,dd=eeee/xx=yy yyy,zz=aaaa,bb=cc ddd/' < file.xml > file2.xml
```

without having to install extra software.

Comment: If you're going to use Perl, then why not parse the XML properly with an XML module?

Comment: Although Perl is available pretty much everywhere by default, there will be barely  any modules available. (Judging by the comments in the question installing stuff will be hard for him)